# Discover which IAM user/role executed Athena query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In Athena I can view the query history for a Workgroup.

I can also get the [query execution details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/get-query-execution.html)

Is there a way to discover who (IAM user/role) executed the query?

Comment: Have you tried https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-tables-search-cloudtrail-logs/ ?

Answer (score 4):

While I couldn't find a way to do this in the Athena console, I found in Cloudtrail when searching the [`StartQueryExecution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html) event